# Why is PUT sent to show() instead of update()?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

This is my `edit()` method:

```
  public static Result edit(Long id)
  {
    User user = User.findById(id);
    Form<User> form = new Form<User>(User.class).fill(user);

    return ok(edit.render(user, form));
  }
```

And in the browser, it sends a `PUT` to `/users/1`.

Here's my route profile:

```
GET     /users/new                  controllers.UsersController.newUser()
POST    /users                      controllers.UsersController.create()
GET     /users/:id                  controllers.UsersController.show(id: Long)
GET     /users/:id/edit             controllers.UsersController.edit(id: Long)
PUT     /users/:id                  controllers.UsersController.update(id: Long)
```

And this is my form:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.UsersController.update(user.id)) {

  @helper.inputText(editUserForm("email"))
  @helper.inputText(editUserForm("username"))
  @helper.inputPassword(editUserForm("password"))

  <button type="submit" name="action" value="update">Update</button>
}
```

However, when I visit `/users/1/edit` and click the update button, the request is sent as `http://localhost:9000/users/1?email=My+Email&username=My+Username&password=My+Password&action=update` instead of as encapsulated form data, and is handled by `show()` instead of `update`.

Can anyone provide more insight into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that browsers only support sending POST or GET requests from a form.  If you have a look at the rendered HTML in your form, you'll see it says something like:

```
<form action="/users/1" method="PUT">
```

But since browsers don't support making PUT requests from forms, the browser ignores the method parameter, and defaults to the default method, that is, GET.  So the browser makes a GET request, and Play handles that accordingly.

So you must only use POST or GET with HTML forms.  There are work arounds, for example, you can use JavaScript to hijack the forms submit, and make a PUT request using AJAX from the forms data instead.

Comment: Yeah. Changing the route to POST does fix the problem. It's kinds strange that Chrome doesn't support PUT. I though it was standard for a while already.

Comment: No, the standard says to only support POST/GET, if Chrome introduced support for other methods, this would actually introduce CSRF vulnerabilities in many websites.